# 'wsprintfW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [80]' to 'LPWSTR'

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

**I have created this simple windows application:**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) ;


int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
     int idmes = MessageBox (NULL, TEXT ("Hello!"), TEXT ("HelloMsg"), MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE) ;

     static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT ("HelloWin") ;
     HWND         hwnd ;
     MSG          msg ;
     WNDCLASS     wndclass ;

     wndclass.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW ;
     wndclass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc ;
     wndclass.cbClsExtra    = 0 ;
     wndclass.cbWndExtra    = 0 ;
     wndclass.hInstance     = hInstance ;
     wndclass.hIcon         = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION) ;
     wndclass.hCursor       = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW) ;
     wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_BACKGROUND+11) ;
     wndclass.lpszMenuName  = NULL ;
     wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName ;

     if (!RegisterClass (&wndclass))
     {
          MessageBox (NULL, TEXT ("This program requires Windows NT!"),
                      szAppName, MB_ICONERROR) ;
          return 0 ;
     }

     hwnd = CreateWindow (szAppName,                  // window class name
                          TEXT ("Programma di emiliano"), // window caption
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,        // window style
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,              // initial x position
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,              // initial y position
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,              // initial x size
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,              // initial y size
                          NULL,                       // parent window handle
                          NULL,                       // window menu handle
                          hInstance,                  // program instance handle
                          NULL) ;                     // creation parameters

     ShowWindow (hwnd, iCmdShow) ;
     UpdateWindow (hwnd) ;

     while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
     {
          TranslateMessage (&msg) ;
          DispatchMessage (&msg) ;
     }
     return msg.wParam ;
}




LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
     HDC         hdc ;
     PAINTSTRUCT ps ;
     RECT        rect ;
     static short xChar, yChar ;
     TEXTMETRIC   tm ;
     char         szBuffer[80];
     int          i ;


     switch (message)
     {
     case WM_CREATE:
          MessageBox (NULL, TEXT ("Ciao caro!"), TEXT ("Salve bellezza"), 0) ;
          hdc = GetDC (hwnd) ;
          GetTextMetrics (hdc, &tm) ;
          xChar = tm.tmAveCharWidth ;
          yChar = tm.tmHeight + tm.tmExternalLeading ;
          ReleaseDC (hwnd, hdc) ;
          return 0 ;

     case WM_PAINT:
          hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
      int iLength;

          for (i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
            { iLength = wsprintf( szBuffer, "The number is %d.", i );
              TextOut (ps.hdc, xChar, yChar * (1 + i), szBuffer, 5) ;
             }
          EndPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
          return 0 ;

     case WM_DESTROY:
          PostQuitMessage (0) ;
          return 0 ;
     }
     return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam) ;
}
```

**but I get this error:**

```
------ Build started: Project: primo, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
Build started 16/01/2011 03:10:02.
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "Debug\primo.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ClCompile:
  All outputs are up-to-date.
  primo.cpp
c:\users\larry\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\primo\primo\primo.cpp(79): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'LONG' to 'short', possible loss of data
c:\users\larry\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\primo\primo\primo.cpp(80): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'LONG' to 'short', possible loss of data
c:\users\larry\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\primo\primo\primo.cpp(90): error C2664: 'wsprintfW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [80]' to 'LPWSTR'
          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Build FAILED.

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.34
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

**Why ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code as follows:

```
TCHAR szBuffer[80];
...
iLength = wsprintf( szBuffer, TEXT ("The number is %d."), i );
```

Comment: Actually this is wrong. `wsprintf` is always Unicode. `TEXT` depends on compilation settings.

Comment: @Remus: not true.  wsprintf will compile for either ANSI (wsprintfA) or Unicode (wsprintfW).  But, I should have declared the string as TCHAR instead of WCHAR.  Fixed.

Comment: I'll be damn, you're right. It takes `LPTSTR`/`LPCTSTR` not `LPWSTR`/`LPCWSTR`.

Answer (score 3):

Be consistent with your ANSI/Unicode strings. You use `TEXT` and `TCHAR` on most palces, but you then mix in hard coded Unicode `wsprintf` and hard coded ANSI `char         szBuffer[80];`. I could tell you that you can simple change the declaration to `WCHAR szBuffer[80];` but that is not true.

First and foremost, you need to be correct. Second, you need to be consistent.

For correctness: `wsprintf` takes Unicode strings as first two arguments. No buts, no ifs. You pass in two ANSI strings, hence the compiler error:

```
WCHAR wszBuffer[80];
...
wsprintf(wszBuffer, L"The number is %d", ...);
```

But you also need to be consistent. If you use `TEXT` and `TCHAR`, stick to `_T` flavour of strings and functions *everywhere*. If you abandon the `_T` (which you should, there is no reason to compile ANSI code in now days), then remove it *everywhere*.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should limit the amount of code you post to that amount that is not working when you post questions.  A great portion of what you posted is superfluous to the problem.

Second, the answer to your problem is you need to use the 'L' prefix for wide character strings, which wsprintf expects (hense the w).  So, `"The number is %d."` should read instead `L"The number is %d."`.  That will fix your current problem.

Comment: I have just added the 'L' prefix but I get the same problem :(

Comment: iLength = wsprintf( szBuffer, L"The number is %d.", i ); right ?

Comment: Yeah, that's right...but notice your other answers.  szBuffer's the wrong type as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  The answers above are missing the fact that the error is on the first parameter: szbuffer, and not on the string constant "The number is %id", which is the second parameter.

I solved the problem by simply casting the first parameter as:

```
   (LPWSTR)szbuffer
```

It stopped the error the compiler was giving me.